# Scrape data from an HTML page that has multiple tabs

Tags: php, jquery, html, web-scraping, tabs

I want to scrape data from [this page](http://m.kikuu.com/product/583500?countryId=2). The page activates the first Tab on page load. I have no problems with scrapping data on the first page (Product Tab). I need to be able to scrape data on the next Tab which is the (Description Tab). How can I programmatically move from the first active Tab to the second tab (Description tab). I am using php to get the html content of the url then use regex to fetch the needed data.

Below is how I fetch the html page content from url:

```
<?php

$html-page-content = file_get_contents("http://m.kikuu.com/product/677925?countryId=2");

#extract data from $html-page-content using regex
# ....
```

I am lost on the part of moving from (Product Tab) to (Description Tab).

Comment: Not easily that's for sure. the tab is loaded at runtime by the client browser from http://images-global.kikuu.com/ProductDetailToQiniu-15879015343108396.html You're probably going to have to scrape the first page and look for that URL structure, then scrape that page too.

Comment: Yes, you would be correct. Did you understand what I wrote?

Comment: The thing is that the second url is being created on the fly with some fancy javascript formula, i have no access to the variable that creates the url (:

Comment: The URL is in the first page's source code, you're going to have to write a regular expression to look for it.

Comment: Nop its not present on the first page. I've already  looked for it and found none.

Comment: View the source of `http://m.kikuu.com/product/583500?countryId=2` and search for `http://images-global.kikuu.com/ProductDetailToQiniu-` you might use `https?://images-global\.kikuu\.com/ProductDetailToQiniu-\d+\.html` as a regex

Comment: @electronicsalim I'm recently come up against the same problem but I'm using VBA and HTTP requests - the issue is the page uses asynchronous calls so in my case (and I believe this applies to you too) is I had to create browser object to simulate interaction.. it's slower and the code is messier but for me at least, there wasn't another way around it

Comment: @Scuzzy I had to look carefully to see it. Thumbs up, i just saw the url that points to the next Tab and the problem is finally solved. Thanks.

Comment: For reference I found this URL by watching the "network" tab of the browser debug console and looking for any XMLHttpRequest activity, then looked into the source code.

Answer (score 1):

This only works for this very specific instance...

The website you are trying to scrape does have a reference to the tab as a url in javascript.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://m.kikuu.com/product/677925?countryId=2');

if( preg_match('%https?://images-global\.kikuu\.com/ProductDetailToQiniu-\d+\.html%', $html, $match) === 1 )
{
  echo file_get_contents($match[0]);
}
```